# how to make Arc menu with scroll?

Tags: android, canvas, menu, scroll, rotation

[image: Arc Menu in scroll]

I need a arc menu like above image but it is not scrolling. I need that i can add more menus and it should come from bottom while scrolling.And these menu will come after a tap on center button. Please help me.

Comment: Do you have some code?

Comment: https://github.com/strider2023/Radial-Menu-Widget-Android/tree/master/src/com/touchmenotapps/radialdemo

Comment: @Vyger i had implemented code from above link of semi circular radial menu but the problem is of scroll that how to implement scroll to rotate menu.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32247810/click-on-fragment-of-semi-circular-radial-menu

Comment: i am also facing the same issue..can you plz help me if you had got soln of it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a `SemiCircularRadialMenu` and there are individual fragments for every menu. I am opening fragments on clicking different menu but when I click on fragment, it also covers that `SemiCircularRadialMenu`. I want that when I click on the fragment, there should be no effect on `SemiCircularRadialMenu`.

My XML Code is given below (XML)

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>

<com.touchmenotapps.widget.radialmenu.semicircularmenu.SemiCircularRadialMenu
    android:id="@+id/radial_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:padding="5dp" />
```

Code link for Semi Circular menu http://hasmukhbhadani.blogspot.in/2014/04/radial-menu-semi-circular-radial-menu.html (CIRCULAR OUTPUT SCREEN: is Semi Circular menu )